# Socket.io MySQL session

Tags: mysql, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

how do i store and access mysql insertId into socket.io session?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router(); 
var https = require('https').createServer( ssl_options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')( https );

io.on('connection', function(socket){

   socket.on('new user', function(data) {

      socket.username = data.username;

      var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO chat SET ?', {subject:'1',message:'2'}, function(err, result) {

         socket.chat_id = result.insertId;

      });

      console.log ( socket.username ) // Username
      console.log ( socket.chat_id ) // Nothing returns?

   });

});
```

Comment: Is chat_id an autoincrement field that you are trying to get?

Comment: @ChrisBarlow yes, it is! can i store the id as session?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your insert is working, so it wouldn't actually have an inserted value.  I think you want to change your insert to something like this.  Also, add a test for the error

```
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO chat (subject, message) VALUES (?, ?)', {subject:'1',message:'2'}, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        return;
    }
    socket.chat_id = result.insertId;
});
```

Comment: the insertid return incremented ID from database.. looks i cant callout the session globally

Answer (score 0):

Like Chris said your parameters don't match the number of elements required for the query. Second problem: usually the second parameter is an array of values instead of an object.
Third problem: You are testing before the query returns a value because your console.log is outside the anonymous callback function.

```
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO chat (subject, message) VALUES (?, ?)', ['1','2'], function(err, rows) {
    socket.chat_id = result.insertId;
    console.log( socket.chat_id);
}
```